# I just flagged a comment on a deleted post - bug?

Tags: bug, comments, flags, deleted-posts

I was looking at [this programming-question-on-meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203896/need-help-to-make-a-online-quiz-project) (10k only), and noticed some comments on it. Not one to let an opportunity for experimentation slip by, I hovered over it:

[image]

I tried to upvote it, but that didn't work. Got a big red nasty box.

Looky there! A flag link!  I bet it doesn't work... Wait, the dialog box came up... Hmm, might as well try it, I bet I get a red box when I hit flag...

[image]

Sorry, mods :).

So apparently I can flag comments on a deleted posts - is it [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)? Or is it a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: Just haphazardly putting a guess in, but there might be sensitive information or illegal things in a comment which may still require attention, even after it's been "deleted".

Comment: That's what I wondered... I suppose we can still flag deleted posts, so we might as well be able to flag comments?

Comment: I’m pretty sure this is by design. We get useful flags on comments on deleted posts from time to time.